# Django somehow looses updated value in form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have one big object - report of users trips. I have provided interface for user to edit some fields in that report one by one. Since the user is can edit one field at a time i have created method which creates modelform based on which field user wants to edit.

It works like that:

```
def createFieldEditorForm(client, field, report_id, request = None):
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    report_instance = get_object_or_404(DriveReport, id = report_id)

    class FieldEditorForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = DriveReport
            fields = ['id', ]

        id = forms.IntegerField(label = _(u"ride_id"), widget=forms.HiddenInput())

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(FieldEditorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            self.build_fields()

        def build_fields(self):
            if field == 'driver_id':
                driver_query = Driver.objects.filter(client = client)
                choices = [('', u'------'),]
                for driver in driver_query:
                    choices.append((driver.id, driver.name))
                self.fields[field] = forms.IntegerField(
                    label = _(u"Drivers"), 
                    widget = forms.Select(
                        choices = choices,
                        attrs = {'data-name':'driver_id'} ),
                    required = False)
            elif field == 'project_id':
                area_query = Area.objects.filter(client = client)
                choices = [('', u'------'),]
                for area in area_query:
                    choices.append((area.id, area.name))
                self.fields[field] = forms.IntegerField(
                    label = _(u"Projects"), 
                    widget = froms.Select(
                        choices = choices,
                        attrs = {'data-name':'project_id'} ),
                    required = False)
            elif field == 'trip_type':
                self.fields[field] = forms.CharField(
                    label = _(u"Projects"), 
                    widget = forms.Select(
                        choices = [(key, value) for key, value in TRIP_TYPE_CHOICES.iteritems()],
                        attrs = {'data-name':'trip_type'} ),
                    required = False)
            else:
                self.fields[field] = forms.CharField(required = False, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'data-name':field} ))

if request is None:
    return FieldEditorForm(instance = report_instance)
else:
    return FieldEditorForm(request, instance = report_instance)
```

And in view

it goes like that:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = createFieldEditorForm(activeaccount, field_id, ride_id, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, _("New field value successfully added/updated"))
    else:
        messages.error(request, _("Value was not saved"))

    return feedback_to_json(request, form)
```

and the outcome is - i get success message in browser, but the field is not updated.

i tried overwriting form.save() method and checking if self.cleaned_data contains [field] - and it does. Its right there. Even if i print out form before save and after save i can see, that the data has reached backend and its all nice and neat.. but the damn value is just not saved/updated into database

Comment: is this happening with this form or with all forms?

Comment: Your code is confusing in that you send request.POST data as a variable named `request`. That definitely threw me off for a minute or so. Just for clarity, I'd rename the `request` variable to `data`.

Comment: Also, it would be much, much cleaner to just create three separate forms and then choose the form class depending on the input. As you have it written it will be hard to read and maintain the code.

Comment: No, the object that can be edited has 15 fields. The 3 visible ones in the code are just the one with foreign keys to other objects and thus need to be added "manually". So creating 15 forms didnt look like very DRY. Nor does creating 3 forms for same thing sound very dry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save functionality of a ModelForm only works on the fields actually in the `fields` attribute. Since you're dynamically adding fields, you'll need to save those manually (save the form with commit=False and then add the data to the unsaved object that's returned).

Comment: Thanks. Ill test it asap - i can add that field that im changing into meta class fields attribute and see if that changes anything.

Comment: this was exactly it. I added the field into Meta fields and it worked just fine. Thanks again Daniel :)